# Python dictionary convert to lowercase?

Tags: python, dictionary, uppercase, lowercase

I have this Python dictionary that needs to be converted to lowercase. The dictionary consists of data that needs to correspond to case insensitive input, e.g. so it will work for resp = 'GBR'  or 'gbr'. Hope I'm making sense here. Any help would be hugely appreciated!

```
resp = raw_input('Which country is ' + record['name'] + ' in? ')
        print " "
        valid = {'GBR': ['GBR',
                        'United Kingdom',
                        'UK',
                        'Great Britain and Northern Island',
                        'GB'
                        ],
                'IRL': ['IRL',
                        'Eire',
                        'Republic of Ireland'
                        ]
            }
        if resp in valid[record['sov']]:
            answ = 'Yes, ' + record['name'] + ' is in the ' + resp
```

Comment: but how do I get this to work for other inputs for resp - i.e. UK, IRL, Eire etc? Thanks

Comment: What is the value of `record`?

Answer (score 5):

If it needs to correspond to case insensitive input, I would suggest simply adding a `.lower()` call when you are doing the comparison between inputs and dictionary values, as opposed to creating/converting a second dictionary just for that.

However, given that your dictionary is already in uppercase, I would use `.upper()` to convert your input uppercase to match your dictionary, instead of doing it the other way around

Comment: It doesn't seem to work as: resp = raw_input('Which country is ' + record['name'] + ' in? ').lower()

Comment: `.lower()` converts a string to lower case. so you would use it as `resp = raw_input('Which country is ' + record['name'].lower() + ' in? ')`

Comment: However, given that your dictionary is already in uppercase, I would use `.upper()` to convert your input uppercase to match your dictionary, instead of doing it the other way around

Comment: Good to hear! Please consider accepting the answer if you found it helpful =)

Answer (score 1):

Basically compare a lowercase version of the response to the lowercase version of the correct answer.

But there's a couple things that aren't completely clear from your question:

What exactly are you storing in `records`?
Which country name should be used in the confirmation *'Yes, ... is in the ...'*?
You want to match the users response against a list of valid synonyms, correct?

If I were to write a city pop quiz game, I'd probably do something like this:

```
import random

cities = {'Dublin': 'IRL',
          'London': 'GBR',
          }

country_synonyms = {'GBR': ['United Kingdom',
                            'GBR',
                            'UK',
                            'Great Britain and Northern Island',
                            'GB',
                            ],
                    'IRL': ['Republic of Ireland',
                            'IRL',
                            'Eire',
                            ]
                    }

# Pick a random city from our dicts' keys
challenge = random.choice(cities.keys())

# Country code of the correct response, e.g. 'GBR'
correct_cc = cities[challenge]

# Assume the canonical name for a country is first in the list of synonyms
correct_name = country_synonyms[correct_cc][0]

response = raw_input('Which country is %s in? ' % challenge)

# Clean any whitespace
response = response.strip()

lowercase_synonyms = [s.lower() for s in country_synonyms[correct_cc]]

if response.lower() in lowercase_synonyms:
    answer = "Yes, %s is in the %s." % (challenge, correct_name)
else:
    answer = "Sorry, that's wrong. %s is in the %s." % (challenge, correct_name)

print answer
```

This line

```
lowercase_synonyms = [s.lower() for s in country_synonyms[correct_cc]]
```

uses a list comprehension to transform every string in the list `country_synonyms[correct_cc]` to lowercase. Another alternative would be to use `map`:

```
import string
# ...
lowercase_synonyms = map(string.lower, country_synonyms[correct_cc])
```

This will map the function `string.lower` to every item in the list `country_synonyms[correct_cc]`.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers shows a proper way to do it, but if you want to convert a dict to lowercase, this is the easiest but not the most effective way:

```
>>> import ast
>>> d
{'GBR': ['GBR', 'United Kingdom', 'UK', 'Great Britain and Northern Island', 'GB'], 'IRL': ['IRL', 'Eire', 'Republic of Ireland']}
>>> ast.literal_eval(str(d).lower())
{'gbr': ['gbr', 'united kingdom', 'uk', 'great britain and northern island', 'gb'], 'irl': ['irl', 'eire', 'republic of ireland']}
```

Edit: global argument in eval.

Edit 2: Using safe "literal_eval":

> This can be used for safely evaluating strings containing Python expressions from untrusted sources without the need to parse the values oneself.

Comment: You should _not_ use `eval` for something like this! If `d` can contain untrusted user input, you just added a security vulnerability to your code.

Comment: What about now, with literal_eval?

Comment: Now you're importing the `ast` module just to convert a dictionary to lowercase? Sorry, but still feels like cracking a nut with a sledgehammer. But +0 because it's safe, and of course correct.

Comment: Last question, what if I've used eval(..., {}) for restricting access?

Comment: Personally I'd probably use `map(string.lower, lst)`. Just uses builtins, short and concise. Doesn't deal with the dict keys (country codes) like yours though.

Comment: I guess using `eval(..., {})` would be safe as well, but it still feels hackish. You're using a string representation of the code for defining the dictionary, lowercase _everything_ in that string, and convert the code to a Python object. That only works "by accident" because the dictionary literal syntax only consists of `{`, `:`, `,` and `}`, no letters where case could matter. That still seems overly complicated and not very elegant to me.